# Browsing Paginated Wagtail CMS Collections

Tags: django, wagtail

Before posting this as an issue on the Wagtail GitHub page, I was hoping there is a coding solution someone could help with here.

I am using Wagtail CMS and love the new 'Collections' feature added.  I created about a dozen collections and then added all my images in their respective collection...works great.  When I view the images in a collection by choosing from the collection dropdown selector, it filters out all my images by collection as it should, but when I click the 'next' link to view the second page, it un-filters and reverts back to showing all images.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to browse through all the filtered collections without it reverting back to all?
2. Is there a way to add a selector at the top to choose how many images to show per page?  Currently there's 20 per page, but it would be nice to be able to 'show all'

I understand that this isn't exactly a specific technical question, but is relevant to the software.  If its better suited as an issue on the Wagtail GH page, let me know - no reason to down-vote; I can delete the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, reported here: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/2700